# ¿Cómo calcular las horas que faltan con LocalTime?

Tags: java

Tengo dos variables del objeto `LocalTime`, una siempre tiene como referencia las ocho de la mañana (`08:00`) y en función de unas horas del día pues el programa te indica qué toca hacer.

Ahora bien, el calendario termina a las `14:30`, y tengo que calcular cuántas horas faltan hasta las 08:00 horas. No se trabaja con días, sólo horas.

Voy a poner lo que realmente me falla, porque el resto funciona bien, es decir, la parte final, cuando son las `14:30` o más tarde y no soy capaz de decir cuántas horas faltan hasta las `08:00`.

```
// Constantes
final String OCHO_HORAS = "08:00";
final String CATORCE_TREINTA_HORAS = "14:30";
final int MINUTOS = 60;

// Variables
LocalTime time;
LocalTime timePass;
timePass = LocalTime.parse(OCHO_HORAS);

// Pido al usuario la hora y los minutos y lo paso a objeto LocalTime
// En función de las horas indica qué hacer
time = LocalTime.of(hora, minutos);

... resto del código
... llego a la parte donde evalúo cuánto tiene falta hasta las 08:00

} else if (time.equals(LocalTime.parse(CATORCE_TREINTA_HORAS)) | (time.isAfter(LocalTime.parse(TRECE_TREINTA_HORAS))) ) {

System.out.println("Faltan: " + time.until(LocalTime.parse(OCHO_HORAS), ChronoUnit.HOURS)
+ " horas y " + time.until(LocalTime.parse(OCHO_HORAS), ChronoUnit.MINUTES) % MINUTOS
+ " minutos para que empiecen.");

}
```

Resultado del programa cuando el usuario indica por ejemplo las `14:31`

> Faltan: -6 horas y -31 minutos para que empiecen.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Buenas ¿Podrías indicarme por favor donde realizas el calculo entre las dos fechas? Que igual esta ahí indicado pero no me ubico.

Comment: El cálculo entre las dos fechas lo hago usando `time.until`, dentro de `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro del until tienes que agregarle un dia para que te regrese el tiempo que falta correctamente, de lo contrario te regresará el tiempo que falta (o el que ya pasó) del mismo día por eso te lo regresa en negativo.

```
LocalTime OCHO_HORAS = LocalTime.parse("08:00:00");

LocalDateTime OCHO_HORAS_UN_DIA_DESPUES = LocalDateTime.parse(
            LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay().toString())
            .plusHours(OCHO_HORAS.getHour()).plusMinutes(OCHO_HORAS.getMinute());


long HORAS_QUE_FALTAN = LocalDateTime.now().until(OCHO_HORAS_UN_DIA_DESPUES, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```